# How to define two way for run code in filter method

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs

I deploy a filter search in react that fetch API, that indicate names entered in the search input, but I want to filter in one of 2 ways.

1. 1way that indicate of name,
2. 2way that indicate through entered symbol

I don't know how I can define **coin.symbol** in filter method

```
const filterCoins = currentCoins.filter(coin =>
  coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
);
```

Generally I want define below line code inside filter method beside **coin.name** that display the result when users search symbol or name.

```
coin.symbol.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: By 2 way, do you mean you're trying to filter coins by name and symbol?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. We need a bit more context. Are you trying to filter data by two different element properties, `name` and `symbol`?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, when user search name or symbol , indicate search result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the result of both conditions.

```
const filterCoins = currentCoins.filter(({ name, symbol }) =>
  name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
  symbol.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
);
```

Or a bit more succinct and **DRY**, place both values into an array as check that at least one of them meets the conditional test.

```
const filterCoins = currentCoins.filter(({ name, symbol }) => 
  [name, symbol].some(el => el.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
);
```

Comment: why we don't use { }  after filter(({name,symbol}) ?

Comment: @SaraNekonam Arrow functions can directly return a value, and thus, aren't required to have a "formal" function body delineated by `{}`, i.e. `() => 1337` is the same as `() => { return 1337; }`. In both versions the ***entire*** expression is processed and the resultant value is returned in the filter callback.